# How can I detect swipe gestures in Compose for Wear OS (with just 1 function)?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os

I want to monitor the whole screen and detect if swipe gestures occur.

How can I do this in one function? Easy short and readable would be great.

Would be nice if you explain the steps so I better understand what needs to be done for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Modifier.swipeable` of WearMaterialApi on your top level container :

```
val swipeState = SwipeableState<String>("initial")
val anchors = mapOf(0f to "left", 1f to "right")

Column(
modifier = Modifier.swipeable(
    state = swipeState,
    anchors = anchors,
    orientation = Orientation.HORIZONTAL,
    enabled = true,
    reverseDirection = false,
    interactionSource = null,
    thresholds = { _, _ -> 
    FractionalThreshold(0.5f) },
    resistance = resistanceConfig(anchors.keys),
    velocityThreshold = Dp(200)
  )
) {
  Text(swipeState.value)
 }
```

It let you define a map of anchors that represent the bounds of the swipe options.

You can make your UI logic around the value of `swipstate`

In the exemple the text will show right if right swipe occured and left if left swipe occured.

If you want to detect **vertical and horizontal swipes at the same times** you can use two `Modifier.swipeable` on a single composable by using `Modifier.then` like that :

```
val horizontalSwipeState = 
SwipeableState<String>("initial")
val horizontalAnchors = mapOf(0f to "left", 
1f to "right")
val verticalSwipeState = SwipeableState<String>("initial")
val verticalAnchors = mapOf(0f to "up", 1f     to "down")

Box(
modifier = Modifier
    .swipeable(
        state = horizontalSwipeState,
        anchors = horizontalAnchors,
        orientation =     Orientation.HORIZONTAL,
        enabled = true,
        reverseDirection = false,
        interactionSource = null,
        thresholds = { _, _ -> FractionalThreshold(0.5f) },
        resistance = resistanceConfig(horizontalAnchors.keys),
        velocityThreshold = Dp(200)
    )
    .then(
        Modifier.swipeable(
            state = verticalSwipeState,
            anchors = verticalAnchors,
            orientation = Orientation.VERTICAL,
            enabled = true,
            reverseDirection = false,
            interactionSource = null,
            thresholds = { _, _ -> FractionalThreshold(0.5f) },
            resistance = resistanceConfig(verticalAnchors.keys),
            velocityThreshold = Dp(200)
        )
    )
) {
Text("Horizontal:                         
${horizontalSwipeState.value} Vertical: 
 ${verticalSwipeState.value}")
}
```

And use a different threshold for each orientation to avoid the two swipes overlaping each others

More info here : https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/wear/compose/material/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).swipeable(androidx.wear.compose.material.SwipeableState,kotlin.collections.Map,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.Orientation,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,kotlin.Function2,androidx.wear.compose.material.ResistanceConfig,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)

Comment: How many direction's this works ?

Comment: And how can i distingush between top to bottom and left to right if this property just give's me 1 float value for both.

**direction**
`code`
    @ExperimentalWearMaterialApi
    val direction: Float
`code`
    The direction in which the swipeable is moving, relative to the current currentValue.
This will be either 1f if it is is moving from left to right or top to bottom, -1f if it is moving from right to left or bottom to top, or 0f if no swipe or animation is in progress.

Comment: I edited my response with your usecase